# Definition of essential maximum and essential supremum

Tags: measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ a bounded domain. Consider $u \in L^1(\Omega)$. The definition of  essential supremum [is well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum).

I am reading the book  "Linear and quasilinear elliptic equations" of Ladyzhenskaya and Ural'tseva. The author use the concept of "essential maximum" and they don't define this concept. I am searching if this concept is the essential supremum but I am not finding anything. Someone know the definition and if is the same thing?

Comment: Would the reasoning of the book make sense if you replace essential maximum by essential supremum? I never read essential maximum anywhere else before, so maybe the author just means the same. It would be weird to have that since if the author chooses a point realizing the essential maximum property one could redefine the function on that very point... so i dont see any benefit in such a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unconventional choice of terminology, either by the authors or by the translators of the book (probably the former). Read "maximum" as "supremum" and "minimum" as "infimum", throughout the book.

This is not limited to "essential" versions; they also write $\max_\Omega u $ with no expectation of the maximum being attained.